# How do I transform elements in comment?

Tags: xml, xslt, comments, transformation

Is it possible to keep elements in a comment when applying an XSLT to a XML-file? I want til transform:

```
<div>
  <!-- <rs type=”bible”>Mos 1</rs> --><note>Hello World</note>
</div>
```

The sample result after the transformation shall be:

```
<newDiv>
  <!-- <rs type=”bible”>Mos 1</rs> --><newNote>Hallo World</newNote>
</newDiv>
```

Comment: Your headline says you want to transform the "elements" hidden in the comment; your first sentence and your example implies you want to keep them "as is". Which is it?

Comment: Note also that the markup `<rs type=”bible”>Mos 1</rs>` inisde of the comment is not well-formed XML as it doesn't use ASCII quote delimiters around the `type` attribute value. While XSLT 3 would allow you to parse well-formed XML (fragments) inside of a comment with `parse-xml` or `parse-xml-fragment` and then transform them and also serialize them back if needed that sample could not be processed that way.

Answer (score 2):

Comments contain a string, not elements. You can preserve a comment by copying it. For example, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div">
    <newDiv>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </newDiv>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
    <newNote>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </newNote>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should produce the result you want (assuming that the change from "Hello to "Hallo" is a typo).

Comment: Maybe explain that a comment() is a type of a node() and so will be matched by your first template.